# b570 virtualization is turned on cant start vmware

Tags: linux, virtualization

I have b570 laptop, turned on intel virtualization technology but when starting vmware also virtualbox it says VTX amd is not supported, running kali linux, any way to run it?

also searched for answers and users fixed it by turning off hyper-v on windows, im running kali linux on linux 4 kernel dont know alternatives

Comment: You have enabled "Intel Virtual Technology" in the BIOS?  Do a complete shutdown/restart (ideally pull power and battery to be sure) as the BIOS doesn't always read/refresh.

Comment: already did it b590 cpu suport virtualisation?

Comment: already enabled in bios and also did complete shutdown